# Need to add Condition to Column Visibility but it is greyed out

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Need a workaround for this. I need to be able to set a conditional expression for this column but it is greyed out. I understand that the reason for this is because I have a row group involved but removing the row group will not provide me with the desired result. I have also tried to use the hidden visibilty in the properties pane, but it just removes the column which creates a white gap in the table.

Any other workarounds out there for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways we have dealt with column visibility and groupings is to create multiple subreports and set them overlapping on each other. You then toggle the visiblity based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a column group you can then set the visibility on the group, rather than the column. This will make this a tablix rather than a tale